# Корректность составления тестового метода / обработка результатов упавшего теста

Tags: java, junit, assets

Всем привет! Имеется тестовый метод(негативная проверка), который проверяет возможность регистрации пользовательской формы с недопустимыми данными в полях "firstName" и "lastName" при валидном заполнении всех остальных полей. Ожидаемый результат - Невозможность регистрации такого пользователя. **То есть в самой форме изначально есть баг**, так как форма допускает регистрацию такого пользователя.

Мой вариант тестового метода таков и тест падает:

```
public class InvalidNameInputTest extends CommonDriverData {
    private String getUrl = "https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form";
    private By firstNameInput = By.xpath("//input[@id='firstName']");
    private By lastNameInput = By.xpath("//input[@id='lastName']");
    private By eMailInput = By.xpath("//input[@id='userEmail']");
    private By mobilePhoneInput = By.xpath("//input[@id='userNumber']");
    private By submitConfirmation = By.xpath("//div[text()='Thanks for submitting the form']");
    private By addressInput = By.xpath("//textarea[@id='currentAddress']");
    private By submitButton = By.xpath("//button[text()='Submit']");

@Test
    public void invalidNamesFieldsFillInFormTest() {
        driver.get(getUrl);
        driver.findElement(firstNameInput).sendKeys("1%!:()<>&",Keys.ENTER);
        driver.findElement(lastNameInput).sendKeys("1%!:()<>&", Keys.ENTER);
        driver.findElement(eMailInput).sendKeys("name@example.com", Keys.ENTER);
        driver.findElement(mobilePhoneInput).sendKeys("1234567890", Keys.ENTER);
        driver.findElement(addressInput).sendKeys("3 Store, 311-318 High Holborn, London, WC1V 7BN", Keys.ENTER);

        WebElement genderInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='gender-radio-1']"));
        Actions genderAction = new Actions(driver);
        genderAction.moveToElement(genderInput).click().perform();

        driver.findElement(submitButton).submit();

        Assert.assertFalse(driver.findElement(submitConfirmation).isDisplayed());
    }
}
```

Тест падает на "assertFalse", так, как форма допускает регистрацию такого пользователя и появляется окно с подтверждением регистрации. Высвечивается текст об успешной регистрации и этот текст соответствует элементу "submitConfirmation". А я ожидаю, что такого элемента быть на странице не должно.

Вопросы:
Правильно ли подобран/составлен Ассерт?
Это нормально, когда при нахождении бага тест падает?
Если да, то:
Каким образом на реальных проектах обрабатываются такие падения? Какие действия следует предпринять тестировщику, чтобы сообщить о данном баге в автоматическом режиме? Через логгирование либо скриншот с последующей отправкой на mail?
Использовал java, JUnit4

Заранее всем спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Не совсем понятна ваша проблема: если ваш (автоматизированный) тест обнаружил баг на форме, вполне нормально, что **тест** будет падать, пока баг не будет исправлен.  На _реальных_ проектах в таких случаях применяется обычный процесс открытия бага в какой-либо системе отслеживания багов типа BugZilla/JIRA и т.п., его исправления и последующей верификации.

Comment: Спасибо, значит все в пордяке... Просто я думал, что в таких ситуациях возможно следует оборачивать ассерт в какой-нибудь: try-catch, чтобы тест проходил и выбрасывал exception... Но если допускается падение теста, вызванное багом и это нормально - значит все норм... Это собственно и хотелось узнать.

Comment: :) Скажем так, в зависимости от проекта возможен вариант, при котором вам понадобится отключить падающий тест и включить его снова после того, когда будет исправлен источник проблемы -- например, чтобы не блокировать какой-нибудь пайплайн или развёртывание более критических изменений.